# Will a Godox 350N trigger a 350o?

Tags: flash, godox, sync

I have a Godox TTL 350o, if I bought a  350N can i use the 'o' model as a triggered external flash?

Answer (score 1):

TT350s can trigger each other cross-brand, ***but you might not get TTL or HSS.***

Unlike the TT685/V860II, the TT350/V350 are not built for cross-brand TTL.  I discovered this when I tried to trigger a TT350-O off-camera from a TT685-C on my Canon 5DMkII. I have the Flashpoint branded versions from Adorama, and their support person emailed me when I mentioned the TT350-O was only firing at full power in TTL (remote power control and HSS worked fine), and said that the TT350 is not designed to do cross-brand TTL.

Different flavor combinations have been reported as working in TTL on dpreview (Sony, Nikon, iirc), so I would test to see.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely yes (supposing that the 350N acting as a commander will be mounted on a Nikon camera). The brand-specific variants of each model (Nikon, Canon, Sony, Olympus and so on) only matter because of the different hotshoes. Their bigger models that do not feature a hotshoe (AD200, AD400, AD600) are all brand-agnostic and work regardless of what's the camera brand as long as the commander matches the camera.

Comment: While that is true of most recent Godox products, it is not true for the TT350 series. Each one is brand specific with regard to TTL and HSS, whether hot shoe mounted or radio controlled. They are cross brand capable for triggering in manual power mode.